# Sending messages between computers

Tags: cocoa, networking

I'd like to start investigating client/server communication. I've started to look at [Distributed Objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DistrObjects/DistrObjects.html) and a tad at [CFNetwork](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Networking/Conceptual/CFNetwork/Introduction/Introduction.html). Let's just say I'm looking for something more my speed (which is slower).

I'd like to be able to send a message from one computer to another, possibly carrying a string or some other type of data. I'm thinking of building a simple student response system where one computer is acting as a server and the clients are connecting and sending data to it.

I'm looking for resources that might help me out as well as suggestions of where to start understanding the concepts involved. I've been teaching myself Objective-C and am a relative newbie to programming, so I know I have holes in my understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Sockets" is the canonical answer.

If you're interested, here's a great introduction to socket programming (biased toward C, but still very informative):

- [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/)

Comment: This got me on the right track. I wasn't sure where to even start. I understand most of that document. It led me to [CocoaAsyncSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket) which I think will provide me with a good enough level of abstraction as I get up to speed. Thanks.

Comment: @Tim Hart: Excellent - glad to hear it!  thank you for following up!

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it really simple is by letting the server set up a local http server (inside it self), and then let the clients simply make http requests. By doing that you let the http layer do all the fancy sockets stuff. More simple, and with more overhead, but may be suitable for your case. Also a lot easier to debug, since you can use your browser to test the connection. There are many ways of implementing a HTTP server in cocoa, can't remember which one i've used, but a quick google pointed me at [this one](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer) for example